# List all IE Browser Modes and select one

Tags: javascript, ie8-browser-mode

Is there a way to list all possible Browser `Modes` and select one that the browser will use on this web page?
I need  `js` or `angular` way, without `jQuery`, or just the `tags` to use in mu `head` section.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to determine which modes a browser supports.

The only ways to change them, from the page itself, are:

- By specifying a Doctype which can trigger Quirks, Standards, or Almost Standards mode depending on the browser.
- By setting `x-ua-compatible` with a meta tag (IE only, and deprecated in IE11)

As far as I know, you can't change the mode with JavaScript from within the page.